# Pine scripts tradingview I've successfully added a strategy to my chart, but it doesn't generate orders

Tags: pine-script

-1

I got ChatGPT to write me this strategy for TradingView, but it won't generate any orders to backtest. Can I change it so it works? It doesn't put out an syntax-error and there is enough data and paper-money to open positions, so I don't understand where the problem is... thanks in advance

```
//@version=5
strategy("Custom Strategy", overlay=true)

// Chandelier Exit
long_period = input(1, title="Chandelier Exit Long Period")
atr_multiplier = input(2, title="ATR Multiplier")
long_exit = ta.lowest(low, long_period) - atr_multiplier * ta.atr(14)
short_exit = ta.highest(high, long_period) + atr_multiplier * ta.atr(14)

// Zero Lag SMA
sma_period = input(50, title="Zero Lag SMA Period")
sma = ta.sma(close, sma_period)

// Logic buy
buy_signal = low[1] < long_exit[1] and low > long_exit and open > sma and close > sma
sell_signal = high[1] > short_exit[1] and high < short_exit

// Logic sell
sell_signal_short = high[1] > short_exit[1] and high < short_exit and open < sma and close < sma
buy_signal_short = low[1] < long_exit[1] and low > long_exit

// Thực thi giao dịch
if (buy_signal)
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if (sell_signal)
strategy.close("Buy")

if (sell_signal_short)
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
if (buy_signal_short)
strategy.close("Sell")

// Hiển thị nến và chỉ báo
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=close > open ? color.green : color.red)
plot(long_exit, color=color.blue)
plot(short_exit, color=color.red)
plot(sma, color=color.orange)
```

I got ChatGPT to write me this strategy for TradingView, but it won't generate any orders to backtest. Can I change it so it works? It doesn't put out an syntax-error and there is enough data and paper-money to open positions, so I don't understand where the problem is... thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [Generative AI e.g. Chatgpt is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)